# how to get high of a candle which crossover moving average

Tags: pine-script

how to find high of a candle which crossover moving average(25) and enter long position when this high crossees

i am unable to find high of the candle which crosses ma

i have tried this code

```
if close > ta.sma(close, ma1) and close[1] < ta.sma(close,ma1)
    high1 ? high : 0
if close < ta.sma(close, ma1) and close[1] > ta.sma(close,ma1)
    low1 ? low  : 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqRzr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called `ta.crossover` that you could use, but first you should define what value should cross over the moving average for it to be a valid entry point.

For example you could use this to check if the close price has crossed over you MA:

```
long_entry_trigger = ta.crossover(close, ta.sma(close, ma1))
```

After this you can get the high value of the candle like this:

```
high_of_candle_that_crossed_over_ma = long_entry_trigger ? high : 0
```

Although if you want to save that high value for later I would recommend declaring a variable with the `var` keyword and changing the value of that when the cross happens. For example:

```
var high_when_crossing = float(na)
if ta.crossover(close, ta.sma(close, ma1))
    high_when_crossing := high
```